# What is the correct Russian spelling of "Trump"?

Tags: правописание, транслитерация, выбор-имени

What is the correct Russian spelling of the last name of the US President-elect, Donald Trump? I've seen both [**Трамп**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BF,_%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B4) and **Трумп**. Which is correct?

Comment: Tрумп is some kind of stupid joke actually. Also it would be nice if you'll support your claim about you've seen Трумп used by a link.

Comment: excuse me but you are claiming something and refusing to provide an evidence that your claims are actually valid.

Comment: the author of this  question hadn't done any minimal research beforehand and the lack of such research leads to a very low quality question.

Comment: @shabunc: What's the joke?

Comment: This depends on how do you pronounce it.

Comment: @shabunc: Why do you keep reverting my attempt to provide exactly the support you've demanded (so nicely).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Your link is not showing in the post (though it exists in the markup - because it was added incorrectly). Actually googling shows that Google is smart enough to give a link to the wikipedia article on Donald Trump, though all other links are for different people. One of the links is "Израиль: трУмп или Хилка - конец одинаков", where Хилка is obviously stands for Hillary Clinton and both names are obviously incorrect spellings of candidate names.

Comment: @Artemix: I think we use different definitions of "obviously". It may be that I've just mistaken the mission of this site. Is there a different SE that someone with no Russian at all should go to to confirm the correct spelling of a non-Russian name? I'd have thought this was the place, but may not be.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Ok, it may be not so obvious, but giving link to a letmegooglethatforyou is wrong. Partially because google gives different results based on your browsing history, and partially because Трумп (meaning Donald Trump) is quite rare and in such case the results on the first page may be completely different for different users.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius if you want to find the correct spelling of the name of a famous person, find their page on the English site for Wikipedia and then switch to its analogous page in Russian (русский).  Problem solved.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Google, I'm sure, uses its own algorithms to "correct" the mistakes that it thinks are too obvious and give you the relevant data. The mission of this site is to complement the Internet by adding knowledge that is not found in the common dictionaries. So no, if you're not ready to put any effort into learning Russian, this site is probably not for you…

Comment: @Evgeniy: I think what you mean to say when you say "not ready to put any effort into learning Russian" is that the site is intended for people who are learning of have some competence in Russian.

Comment: @KCd: I was seeing to *confirm* exactly that, and thought this might be the place to do so. Clearly it is not.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Then it's fine we agree. :) See, if you have no competence, you cannot ask a good question that is not answered by a simple dictionary look-up, and that's the only problem.

Comment: @Evgeniy: Yes, I see that now. I was just surprised by the nastiness ("no competence", " refusing to provide an evidence", "hadn't done any minimal research", "obvious", "obvious", etc.), since I'd done all the research *I was capable of*. Perhaps it's just a cultural thing (or even a language thing, who would be ironic).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I was not aware of this part of your post "I had naively thought it might be the latter (I don't speak any Russian), and [Googling that][2] results in many clearly Trump-related hits, including the Trump "card" (sorry)." - it explains much (I mean why you have this question). I guess shabunc was offended by letmegooglethatforyou link you provided. Actually all that animation steals time of a person that clicks the link - it's really a bad thing.

Comment: @Artemix: Yes, not only was he offended (apparently) he overreacted and didn't bother explaining his reaction until he'd reverted twice my attempt to explain (at his request). Basically all the confusion here is just down to really bad modding I'm afraid. If this site wants go come out of beta, it needs better mods.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius you actually are an active user of some other stacks. Can you give an honest and sincere answer - what you would expect if you will provide a link for the letmegoogleitforyou instead of actual link? Would you expect downvotes? Would you expect moderator intervention?

Comment: @shabunc: I'm not sure what you mean by "actual link". The point was to show what google produced (and the exact steps I used to get there). If *that's* what set you off, then you should certainly not be a mod. (And note that I got the down votes while that information was removed, by you.)

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius  you didn't answer the question I've asked you but it's totally valid behavior. OK, let me make it clear -  pasting links to sites like letmegooglethatforyou won't be tolerated on this particular stack.

Comment: @shabunc: That may well be (it's a legitimate policy, though it context it made some sense: it was intended to demonstrate exactly what I did and how that represented a dead end for me as a non-Russian speaker). The issue that needs to be addressed though is your inappropriate reaction and your unsuitability as a mod.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Сorrect Russian spelling of the last name of the US President-elect, Donald Trump - Трамп.